# How to set C# class attribute into C++/CLI class

Tags: c#, attributes, c++-cli

I want to set testcase attribute into my c++/cli class. i am adding the dll reference for that attribute. Note here that the dll which i am using for attribute setup which is in C#. please find below code:

```
using namespace Sample::Generic::TestAutomation::TestSystem;
namespace ClassLibrary1 {

[AttributeUsage(Sample::Generic::TestAutomation::TestSystem::TestCase)]
    public ref class Class1 : public Sample::CheckIt::TestPool::TestCase
    {
    private:
        static Class1^ Instance = nullptr;
        GenericLogger^ Switchmodule_log;
        TAIoPortClient^ _generalio;
        bool _testCaseInit = false;
   };
```

When i am trying to use this attribute, i am getting below error:

> Error C2275   'Sample::Generic::TestAutomation::TestSystem::TestCase':
>   illegal use of this type as an
>   expression    ClassLibrary1   c:\users\chan\documents\visual studio
>   2015\projects\classlibrary1\classlibrary1\ClassLibrary1.h 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AttributeUsage` is for when you define a new attribute. When you define MyFancyNewAttribute, you use `AttributeUsage` to declare whether the attribute is used on classes, or methods, or whatever.

You're overthinking this. To use the attribute, it's the same syntax as in C#.

```
[TestCase]
public ref class Class1
```

Comment: Thanks david, for the answer but i have given same way which is mentioned above, that is working for C# but not working on C++/CLI. When i tried with, i am getting this error: "Could not load TestCases from the ClassLibrary1!Assembly has no TestCases defined"

Comment: My understanding is that my test application is not able to get the test case attribute.

Comment: That's a different question. Maybe post a new question with the test framework tagged.

Comment: I fixed my problem to update the dll references. it works for me.